How to mock web3 method call
How would one mock this call to a ethereum smart contract using the web3 js library.
export const getERC20Balance = async (
  web3Client: Web3,
  tokenAddress: string,
  walletAddress: string
) => {
  const balanceOfAbi = getERC20ABIOfInterest('balanceOf');
  const contract = new web3Client.eth.Contract(balanceOfAbi, tokenAddress);
  const result = await contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call();
  if (!result) return;

  const resultInEther = web3Client.utils.fromWei(Number(result), 'ether');

  return resultInEther
};

more specifically, const contract = new web3Client.eth.Contract(balanceOfAbi, tokenAddress); const result = await contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call();
I've tried mocking the library using mockDeep but get TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'balanceOf')

Show the code you have tried.

jest.mock('web3', () => {   const web3 = jest.requireActual('web3');   jest.spyOn(web3, 'Contract').mockReturnValue({     Contract: () => ({       methods: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({         // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars         balanceOf: (_walletAddress: string) => ({           call: jest.fn(),         }),       })),     }),   });
